# How to lock the screen from keyboard (ctrl+cmd+q) without making display turn off on Big Sur?

Tags: macos, display, big-sur

Currently on macOS Big Sur, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> locks the screen but also turns the display off. I have an external monitor and in this setup it is very slow to bring the screen back after touching any key after locking.

**So I would like to lock the screen (best using the same shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>)) without turning the display off.**

How to get that behaviour?

There are some apps like Amphetamine which could give me similar behaviour **but** they also change many other behaviours of the system and I *do not* want that. I want system sleep, screensaver etc to behave as usual for example. Which mostly rules out most of such apps.

There should be some setting hidden in the system itself I assume. I wasn't able to find it though.